# WPF: Best way to create a control that can used in multiple views

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have 5 pages that all have this grid structure:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid Grid.Row="0">
    <!-- TOP CONTENT HERE -->
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <!-- MIDDLE CONTENT HERE -->
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <!-- BOTTOM CONTENT HERE -->
</Grid>
```

Now obviously this is simplified just for this question - but what I want to avoid, is to have the exact same Grid layout with all styles etc, in each view.

Question is, how can I in the most simple way create a control that View1, View2..ViewN can add to their xaml and specify TOP, MIDDLE and BOTTOM content as they see fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple derived Grid would automatically arrange three child elements as desired:

```
public class AutoGrid : Grid
{
    public AutoGrid()
    {
        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto) });
        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto) });
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++)
        {
            SetRow(Children[i], i);
        }

        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a clever way to do this. My first thought was a user control with ContentPresenters bound to DependencyProperties on the user control.

Comment: That *is* clever. Yet I also need to apply some styles on AutoGrid (e.g. like borders and colors). Would I do this by adding a static resource to each View and then set "<c:AutoGrid Style="{StaticResource MyAutoGridStyle}">"? Yes, I'm new to wpf...

Comment: @Werner You could make AutoGrid a regular "custom control" as explained in [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview). There would be a file `Themes/Generic.xaml` with a default Style for AutoGrid.

Comment: Or simpler, just declare a default Style resource in your application with `TargetType=local:AutoGrid` but without `x:Key`.